# Dart with Maven (in Spring Boot App)

Tags: maven, dart, spring-boot

I like Dart, I have been playing with it for a while. I'd like to integrate with my Maven web app project based on Spring Boot.

I suppose the correct way is to use dart-maven-plugin. But I'm not sure how to properly glue it in place. Spring Boot has its own structure, Maven as well and Dart makes that none the better.

I will need probably the entry point for Dart part, means Spring Boot templates folder needs to include the html resources from Dart.

I would appreciate any idea, best practices.

PS: the aforementioned dart-maven-plugin is not really vivid, should I be afraid using it at all, as I don't see any progress there, compared to Dart itself.

**UPDATE**

So this can be solution(note I have only one so called "entry point"- .dart file so far)

1. normal Dart structure in src/main/dart
2. user dart-maven-plugin's pub build command into ${project.build.directory}/dart
3. maven-resources-plugin:copy-resources from ${project.build.directory}/dart/web to ${project.build.directory}/classes/public/
4. make war

I'm still able to use Intellij's Dart integration from src/main/dart.
The Spring Boot maps classes/public/ folder to / so the dart file and html files are loaded properly.

It's not ideal, but it works so far. Please fell free to write down any comments.

Comment: Think is as my src/main/dart folder follow Dart structure, so I can develop directly from there, but the problem is after I would like to move dart2js`ed .js files to Spring Boot the same for html as the links in them will not fit:(

Comment: I think Gradle is more flexible and suitable to your need, see my https://github.com/sdeleuze/opensnap GitHub repository for a real example.

Comment: Change the build system, can be option, although not in my case. The question is also how to use compiled dart.js and still be able to use dart structure as is for dev.

Comment: @SébastienDeleuze looks like your project has complete separate Dart part and you are not utilizing dart2js. I need the .js to be able to run on different browsers.

Comment: I am using dart2js, and the Java part has a profile to use directly Dart file in dev mode.

Comment: I didn't find any reference to dart2js compiling at first glance. Can you show me where, please.

Comment: See my answer to this post that has a solution for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923232/how-to-build-dart-project-with-maven/35533948#35533948

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a few times to use dart in a maven project myself and always ran into some problems. Right now I'm developing my dart apps in a separate module that I build with pub which connects to the maven based java backends with rest.

This has several advantages for me, for example:

- I can use pub and avoid problems with outdated maven plugins
- I use the serving mechanism that fits best for the static dart code and assets (in my case a docker image with nginx)
- I have a clean separation of backend and frontend code with a tailored REST API

As I like the microservice approach I also use spring session together with zuul (via spring-cloud).

If you want to combine dart with generated html from for example JSPs or another templating engine, then this isn't a good approach for you. But IMHO dart is not yet very well suited for these kind of architectures.