# How to build dart project with dart-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, web, plugins, dart

I need to build my Dart project with Maven.

I've found [dart-maven-plugin](https://github.com/dart-maven-plugin/dart-maven-plugin) for this goal, and it works fine for resolving dependencies.

In Dart I compile my project with two commands:

1. `pub get`
2. `pub build`

So, when I write

```
mvn dart:pub
```

it gets all dependencies.

Now I need to build my project. So, I write

```
mvn dart:pub -DpubCommand=build
```

but it's still resolving dependencies, it doesn't build the project!

How can I build project with [dart-maven-plugin](https://github.com/dart-maven-plugin/dart-maven-plugin)?

Comment: `But it doesn't work` expand it

Comment: Sorry, it works, but it resolve dependencies like if I'd run get command. I mean when I run "mvn dart:pub -DpubCommand=build" it shows me next output:<br/>[INFO] Run pub for package root: f:\Maven\dart-maven-plugin-example\src\main\dart\range
Resolving dependencies...
Got dependencies!<br/>
[INFO] Run pub for package root: f:\Maven\dart-maven-plugin-example\src\main\dart\rom<br/>
Resolving dependencies...<br/>
Got dependencies!
[INFO] Run pub for package root: f:\Maven\dart-maven-plugin-example\src\main\dart\polymer
Resolving dependencies...
Got dependencies!

Comment: It doesn't build nothing! But I need build my project.

Comment: Can't you just run `pub build` as a shell command from maven?

Comment: Well, I think this is not the best idea, cause I have plugin for this purpose. It's like go by foot when you have bus tickets. But if plugin will not work I can use you idea as plan B.

Comment: If you don't have any special requirements which `pub build` can't  fulfill on its own, then using a plugin might be overkill. I guess the plugin was started when `pub` didn't yet exist and `dart2js` was the only option. Back then the plug-in was probably a big win,  but became somewhat redundant with the introduction of `pub`.

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote wrong parameter name. Correctly will be:

```
    mvn dart:pub -Ddart.pub.command=build
```

Also there is example project name - "dart-maven-plugin-example"
Don't build this project, it will not build cause there is no web folder in some sub-projects.
Hope it will help some one else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this you can just add this ant plugin to your project:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <exec executable="cmd" osfamily="windows" dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/dart/home">
                        <arg value="/c"/>
                        <arg value="pub.bat"/>
                        <arg value="build"/>
                    </exec>
                    <exec executable="/bin/sh" osfamily="mac" dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/dart/pegboard">
                        <arg value="-c"/>
                        <arg value="pub build --mode=debug"/>
                    </exec>
                    <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/static">
                        <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/dart/your-dart-project-name/build/web">
                            <include name="*/**"/>
                        </fileset>
                    </copy>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

These two ant tasks will run 'pub build' and then copy your build files to the approriate directory. This here is set up for a spring boot app that is serving files from the static folder. You can change the locations of the files. Replace the 'your-dart-project-name' with your dart project name. The '*/**' is an ant matcher that will match all files recursively.

The exec command requires that you have added your dart-sdk 'bin' folder to your classpath. That will let pub be executable.